# Why is my GET request not working? - CORS + Express + FetchAPI

Tags: node.js, express, fetch-api, connection-refused

I am trying to run a simple GET request from my client-side vanilla JS to my ExpressJS server - my client is running on an nginx static server on port 80, while my Express server is running on nodejs on port 3000.

I keep getting chrome error message:

`GET http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Client-side JS:

```
async function ping() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000');
    return response;
}
```

Server-side JS:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json);
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello world!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

If someone could help me with this it would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! `app.use(express.json)` should be `app.use(express.json())`, but I don't know whether that solves your problem already.

Comment: I have replicated your code and on google chrome `http://localhost:3000` i got the hello world

Comment: Connection refused suggests no server is actually running on localhost:3000

Answer (score -1):

i have copied your server code to a server.js file and changed the `app.use(express.json)` to  `app.use(express.json())` or remove it completely and when opening `http://localhost:3000/` I got

[image]

so the only problem in your code is the line i've mentioned, BTW when i copied your exact code i got a timeout eventually and not conection refused.